# Getting index out of error when reloading table view

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, swift3

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    let order =  orders[indexPath.row]
    guard orders.count > indexPath.row else {
        print("Index out of range")
        return
    }
    
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    var viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "viewControllerIdentifer") as! OrderDetailsController
    viewController.passedValue = order.id
    self.present(viewController, animated: true , completion: nil)      
}
```

Whenever I close my app (go to background) and reopen it it crashes.

> fatal error: Index out of range
>
> 2017-06-18 18:09:33.726310 JaeeDriver[1378:563304] fatal error: Index out of range

I have no idea why it does this. It's important to note that in `ViewDidLoud`I have this line of code to update my table

```
var timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(
    timeInterval: 4, 
    target: self, 
    selector: "GetOrders", 
    userInfo: nil, 
    repeats: true
)
```

and whenever the update happens, I have this code in the beginning of `GetOrders` function

```
func GetOrders (){   
    orders = []
    ...
}
```

to remove the old data and replace it with the new one

*Update*

at the end of `GetOrder`

```
func GetOrders (){   
    orders = []
    ....
    ....
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.tableview.reloadData()
    }
}
```

number of sections and rows :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return orders.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
     let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "OrderCell", for: indexPath) as! OrderCell
    
    let entry = orders[indexPath.row]
    
    cell.DateLab.text = entry.date
     cell.shopNameLab.text = entry.shopname
    cell.shopAddLab.text = entry.shopaddress
    cell.nameClientLab.text = entry.clientName
    cell.clientAddLab.text = entry.ClientAddress
    cell.costLab.text = entry.Cost
    cell.perefTimeLab.text = entry.PerferTime
    cell.Shopimage.hnk_setImage(from: URL(string: entry.Logo))
    return cell
}
```

Any help please would be appreciated.

Comment: Call `tableView.reloadData()` whenever your `orders` array changes.

Comment: please check my updated question

Comment: break point your app where you get let order and see indexPath and orders.count

Comment: in this line   >>>     let order =  orders[indexPath.row]

Comment: Update your question with your `numberOfSections` and `numberOfRowsInSection` methods.

Comment: just did check it please

Answer (score 1):

I think you should need to add one more array say temporder . add fresh list in this after getting fresh list change array data of order with temporder and reload it. You are clearing order data and selecting list item from table view. But at that time fresh data didn't added in order array .

Comment: Thank you man. Do you mine adding a little bit of code to understand this clearly please

Comment: pleas if you can help me here I'd appreciate it