# Updating code to latest Swift 4 syntax results in a "Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range" error

Tags: ios, swift

I'm currently in the process of updating some apps to the latest Swift 4 syntax and have run into a problem, and I'm sure I'm just missing something really obvious.

Initially my code was as follows:

```
    let indices : [Int] = [0,1,2,3]
    //let newSequence = shuffle(indices)
    let newSequence = indices.shuffle()
    var i : Int = 0
    for(i = 0; i < newSequence.count; i++)
    {
        let index = newSequence[i]
        if(index == 0)
        {
            // we need to store the correct answer index
            currentCorrectAnswerIndex =  i

        }
```

Initially I had three error with the above code, namely:

1. `Value of type '[Int]' has no member 'shuffle'`
2. `C-style for statement has been removed in Swift 3`
3. `Unary operator '++' cannot be applied to an operand of type '@lvalue Int'`

To address these I changed the code so that it's now as follows:

```
    let indices : [Int] = [0,1,2,3]
    //let newSequence = shuffle(indices)
    let newSequence = indices.shuffle()
    var i : Int = 0
    while i < newSequence.count {i += 1

        let index = newSequence[i]
        if(index == 0)
        {
            // we need to store the correct answer index
            currentCorrectAnswerIndex =  i

        }
```

After changing the code and running a Product > Clean within Xcode, I no longer have any errors. However, when I use the app in the iOS Simulator it hangs at a certain point and checking within Xcode gives me the `Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range` error on the following line of code:

```
let index = newSequence[I]
```

I've read through other questions about the same error in Swift (see: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44616460/4353060), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47355509/4353060), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44731707/4353060) and [4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46863774/4353060)) but these don't seem to apply in my scenario.

I know I'm missing something really obvious here, but at present it's just escaping me.

Any thoughts?

Comment: *Any thoughts?* – Yes: Debug your code. If `newSequence[i]` gives an index out of range error, add `print(i)` before that line. Then you would see quickly were your error is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Swift 3+ equivalent of the code is

```
let indices : [Int] = [0,1,2,3]
let newSequence = indices.shuffle() // this seems to be a custom function

for i in 0..<newSequence.count
{
    let index = newSequence[i]
    if index == 0 { // no parentheses in Swift
        // we need to store the correct answer index
        currentCorrectAnswerIndex = i
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change position of (incrementing value) `i` as shown in below code. (Value of `i` is increment before it is used in loop operations, hence during final/last iteration of loop, value of `i` becomes larger than array indices)

```
let indices : [Int] = [0,1,2,3]
//let newSequence = shuffle(indices)
let newSequence = indices.shuffle()
var i : Int = 0
while i < newSequence.count {

    let index = newSequence[i]
    if(index == 0)
    {
        // we need to store the correct answer index
        currentCorrectAnswerIndex =  i

    }
    i += 1 // Update (increment) value for i at last
}
```

#### Update

(As suggested by MartinR) This would be better than you did:

```
let indices : [Int] = [0,1,2,3]
let newSequence = indices.shuffle()

for (i, newSeqIndex) in newSequence.enumerated() {
    if (newSeqIndex == 0) {
        currentCorrectAnswerIndex =  i
    }

}
```

Comment: Better: `for i in 0..< newSequence.count` or `for i in newSequence.indices`

Answer (score 2):

The reason for crash is that you increment `i`, perform some operations with it, and only then check if it is not out of range. To get rid of this error just move `i += 1` to the end of your closure.

But why not use fast enumeration? You're still trying to do a loop the old way, but with new syntax. Instead of doing it C way

```
var i : Int = 0
while i < newSequence.count {
    let index = newSequence[i]
    if(index == 0)
    {
        // we need to store the correct answer index
        currentCorrectAnswerIndex =  i

    }

    i += 1
}
```

do it the correct Swift way

```
for (index, value) in newSequence.enumerated() {
    if value == 0 {
        currentCorrectAnswerIndex =  index
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You put a `i += 1` in there that isn't in the original code.